# Вызов другой функции из case aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Имеется инлайн кнопка с настройками, не понимаю как сделать переход к функции set_gender.

```
@settings_router.callback_query(SettingsCbFac.filter(F.action == "get_settings"))
async def get_settings(callback: CallbackQuery, callback_data: SettingsCbFac,
                       _user: User, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
    match callback_data.value:
        case 'gender':
            await callback.message.answer("Укажите свой пол", reply_markup=await 
SettingsCbFac.gender_kd_fab('male', 'female'))
        case 'age':
            pass
        case 'cancel':
            pass

    await callback.answer()

    await callback.answer()
    with suppress(TelegramBadRequest):
        await bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)

@settings_router.message(SettingsCbFac.filter(F.action == 'set_gender'), 
Settings.gender)
async def set_gender(callback_data: SettingsCbFac, message: Message, _user: User):
    match callback_data.value:
        case 'male':
            _user.gender = 'male'
            await message.answer('Главное меню')
        case 'female':
            _user.gender = 'female'
            await message.answer('Главное меню')
```

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: Спасибо, видел, но тут обычный текст от юзера + без коллбеккуери(